# Add Temp Folders (endpoints) to Azure Storage Blob Container with an Empty Text File

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm looking to add some initial folders as part of a project setup (a project being nothing but a folder containing some subfolders, which contain project files).

When browsing the blob container, the folders in the list of string within the code should have this path structure:

```
Project01\Photos\Main\can_be_deleted.txt
```

Where `Main` appears as a folder and `can_be_deleted.txt` appears as a file within it. My reason for being so specific is to match other software that uploads and manages data with this formatting. Currently, with the code below, the results are per the attached image, which doesn't work for us.

As a bonus, if there was a way to add the `.txt` files without first saving one on the local computer, that would be best.

```
    public static void CreateInitial(string ProjectName)
    {
        // Create default BLOB structure for the new project
        List<string> folderNames = new()
        {
            projectName + @"\Photos\Main",
            projectName + @"\Photos\Other",
            projectName + @"\SupportingFiles\Main",
            projectName + @"\ZipFiles"
        };
        BlobServiceClient bSvcCl = GetStorageAccountTest(_StorageConnectionString);

        BlobContainerClient contCl = bSvcCl.GetBlobContainerClient(_ActiveProjectsContainer);

        File.Open(@"C:\can_be_deleted.txt", FileMode.Create).Close();
        foreach (var folderName in FoldersNames)
        {                
            BlobClient blobCl = contCl.GetBlobClient(folderName);
           
            //blobCl.Upload(BinaryData.FromString("can_be_deleted.txt"), false, default);
            blobCl.Upload(@"C:\can_be_deleted.txt");

        }
        File.Delete(@"C:\can_be_deleted.txt");
    }
```

[image: Results with posted code]

Answer (score 0):

I am not at my PC, but you can give this a try:

```
public static async Task<bool> CreateInitial(string ProjectName)
{
    List<string> folderNames = new()
    {
        projectName + @"\Photos\Main",
        projectName + @"\Photos\Other",
        projectName + @"\SupportingFiles\Main",
        projectName + @"\ZipFiles"
    };

    foreach (var folderName in FoldersNames)
    {
        var blobContainer = new BlobContainerClient(
            "YOUR_AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING",
            folderName
        );
        blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(PublicAccessType.None);
        
        var binaryData = new BinaryData(""); // This will be the empty file data you need
        var uploadResponse = await blobContainer.UploadBlobAsync(
            "can_be_deleted.txt",
            binaryData,
            CancellationToken.None
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

This should create an in-memory instance for your empty file and upload it to the correct path on your azure storage.

Comment: `blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(PublicAccessType.None);` generated the error `: 'The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.`

Comment: I tried this but still no dice:               `BlobServiceClient bSvcCl = GetStorageAccountTest(_StorageConnectionString);
                BlobContainerClient conCl = bSvcCl.GetBlobContainerClient(_ActiveProjectsContainer + folderName);`

Comment: A quick search guided me to this: https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip79.html, maybe you could use it to work in your current scenario

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for finding that. Feel free to update your answer.